# Keep getting [Object Object] in hybrid app Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm building a hybrid app using Nuxt JS, Cordova and Cordova Native Storage (essentially localstorage).

I'm saving an object to native storage, and retrieving it on page load within `mounted()` however, I keep getting the following error no matter what I try to access the object data:

`[Object Object]`

My JS in the component which is loaded on every page is:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.getNativeStorage(), false)
  },
  methods: {

    getNativeStorage() {
      window.NativeStorage.getItem("beacon_native_storage", (value) => {
        var parseObj = JSON.parse(value)
        alert(parseObj)
        alert(parseObj.localStorage)
      }, (error) => {
        alert(`Error: ${error.code}-${error.exception}`)
      });
    },

    refreshNativeStorage(currentState) {
      window.NativeStorage.initWithSuiteName("beacon");
      window.NativeStorage.setItem("beacon_native_storage", JSON.stringify(currentState), () => {
        alert('Stored currentState')
      }, (error) => {
        alert(`Error: ${error.code}`)
      });
    }

  },
  computed: {
    state () {
      return this.$store.state
    }
  },
  watch: {
    state: {
      handler: function (val, Oldval) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          this.refreshNativeStorage(this.state)
        }.bind(this), 10)
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
```

And the object from Vuex looks like:

```
export const state = () => ({
  pageTitle: 'App name',
  dataUrls: [],
  intervalData: [],
  settings: [],
  experimentalFeatures: [],
  customAlertSeen: false,
  user: null,
  account: null,
  payloadOutput: null
})
```

Every time the `getItem` runs, `alert(parseObj)` always returns `[Object Object] rather than for instance, the data. And if I try returning`parseObj.localStorage.pageTitle`which is clearly defined in`store/localStorage.js`it returns`undefined`

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, what happens, is that localStorage stores STRINGS, not objects.

When you save your item to localStorage, first convert it to a string, then parse it from a string when you retrieve it.

```
localStorage.setItem('a', {b:'c',d:'e'})

localStorage.getItem('a')  // "[object Object]" <- note the quotes!

localStorage.setItem('a', JSON.stringify({b:'c',d:'e'}))

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('a')) // {b: "c", d: "e"}
```